# How to improve performance while iterating through a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I have two pandas data frames. The first one contains a list of unigrams extracted from the text, count and probability of the unigram occurring in the text. The structure looks like this:

```
unigram_df
    word            count       prob
0   we              109         0.003615
1   investigated    20          0.000663
2   the             1125        0.037315
3   potential       36          0.001194
4   of              1122        0.037215
```

The second one contains a list of skipgrams extracted from the same text, along with the count and probability of the skipgram occurring in the text. It looks like this:

```
skipgram_df
    word                      count         prob
0   (we, investigated)        5             0.000055
1   (we, the)                 31            0.000343
2   (we, potential)           2             0.000022
3   (investigated, the)       11            0.000122
4   (investigated, potential) 3             0.000033
```

Now, I want to calculate the pointwise mutual information for each skipgram, which is basically a log of skipgram probability divided by the product of its unigrams' probabilities. I wrote a function for that, which iterates through the skipgram df and and it works exactly how I want, but I have huge issues with performance, and I wanted to ask if there is a way to improve my code to make it calculate the pmi faster.

Here's my code:

```
def calculate_pmi(row):
    skipgram_prob = float(row[3])
    x_unigram_prob = float(unigram_df.loc[unigram_df['word'] == row[1][0]]
    ['prob'])
    y_unigram_prob = float(unigram_df.loc[unigram_df['word'] == row[1][1]]
    ['prob'])
    pmi = math.log10(float(skipgram_prob / (x_unigram_prob * y_unigram_prob)))
    result = str(str(row[1][0]) + ' ' + str(row[1][1]) + ' ' + str(pmi))
    return result 

pmi_list = list(map(calculate_pmi, skipgram_df.itertuples()))
```

Performance of the function for now is around 483.18it/s, which is super slow, as I have hundreds of thousands of skipgrams to iterate through. Any suggestions would be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: You should simply avoid iterating through rows, and aim to convert it to pandas functions such that processing can be done in batck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question, and exercise, for new users of `pandas`. Use `df.iterrows` only as a last resort and, even then, consider alternatives. There are relatively few occasions when this is the right option.

Below is an example of how you can vectorise your calculations.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

uni = pd.DataFrame([['we', 109, 0.003615], ['investigated', 20, 0.000663],
                    ['the', 1125, 0.037315], ['potential', 36, 0.001194],
                    ['of', 1122, 0.037215]], columns=['word', 'count', 'prob'])

skip = pd.DataFrame([[('we', 'investigated'), 5, 0.000055],
                     [('we', 'the'), 31, 0.000343],
                     [('we', 'potential'), 2, 0.000022],
                     [('investigated', 'the'), 11, 0.000122],
                     [('investigated', 'potential'), 3, 0.000033]],
                    columns=['word', 'count', 'prob'])

# first split column of tuples in skip
skip[['word1', 'word2']] = skip['word'].apply(pd.Series)

# set index of uni to 'word'
uni = uni.set_index('word')

# merge prob1 & prob2 from uni to skip
skip['prob1'] = skip['word1'].map(uni['prob'].get)
skip['prob2'] = skip['word2'].map(uni['prob'].get)

# perform calculation and filter columns
skip['result'] = np.log(skip['prob'] / (skip['prob1'] * skip['prob2']))
skip = skip[['word', 'count', 'prob', 'result']]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I needed. Execution time on 60k skipgrams is now down from 2 minutes to 10 seconds :)